# Postasync from API to MVC Controller doesn't work in published app

Tags: c#, rest, httpclient

I have a solution with multiple services REST that communicate with `httpClient` with a MVC Controller. In an special case, in local, when I try to do the following:

```
public async Task<byte[]> SendParte(ParteDC parte)
{    
    // Passing an json content
    var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
    // it returns in MVC Controller an byte[]


    // then, 
    bytearray = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return bytearray ;
 }
```

More or less this is the code, I´m writing what I remember. But the case is that when I execute in my local it works fine, but if I publish the API and the MVC separated in both sites in IIS, the `PostAsync` doesn't work.